# Htaccess-How to redirect from website.com/index.php?route=action to website.com/action

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

Im a newbie about htaccess. When people go to mywebsite.com/index.php?route=action I want redirect to mywebsite.com/action.Anyone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it could be helpful to you

## Redirect a path to another file path

Redirect /index.php?route=action http://mywebsite.com/action

Comment: Thanks, but parameter route=action is example, the action is dynamic. I can't do this.